# B is obtained from A by elementary row operations, where A,B are 3x3 matrices in the reals then prove they have the same rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A,B \in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ if a series of *``Elementary Row Operations"* are performed on them how do we show they have the same rank? Where I believe rank is the dimension of the span of the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think about the problem: elementary row operations are linear combinations of row vectors that do not change the span of the rows.

For instance, let

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a^1_1    & \cdots & a^1_n   \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \vdots   \\
a^m_1    & \cdots & a^m_n
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^1 \\
\vdots \\
a^m
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, if you interchange rows $i$ and $j$, obviously the span of the row vectors $[a^1 , \dots , a^m]$ doesn't change:

$$
[\dots , a^i , \dots , a^j, \dots] = [\dots , a^j , \dots , a^i, \dots]  \ .
$$

The same happens if you multiply one row by some $\lambda \neq 0$:

$$
[\dots , \lambda a^i , \dots ] = [\dots , a^i , \dots]
$$

because every linear combination you can do with the vectors on the right is also a linear combination with the vectors on the left and vice versa:

$$
\dots + \alpha_i (\lambda a^i ) + \dots = \dots + (\alpha_i \lambda ) a^i  + \dots
$$

and

$$
\dots + \alpha_i  a^i  + \dots = \dots + \frac{\alpha_i}{\lambda} (\lambda a^i ) + \dots
$$

Finally, if you add two rows, you also have

$$
[\dots , a^i , \dots , a^j, \dots ] = [\dots , a^i , \dots , a^i + a^j, \dots ] \ .
$$

Exercise: why?

Comment: Just wondering, are the square braces standard notation for denoting the span of a set of vectors? I often see angle brackets instead, or even just $span\{\mathbf{a}_1,\cdots\}$

Comment: Yes. I mean: it's standard for me, maybe.  :-) Perhaps this is not standard in the USA or Anglo-Saxon countries?

Answer (score 1):

By construction/definition, ERO's preserve the solution set of a system Ax=b (trivial to see for exchanges and for scaling, a little harder for shears ), so that, in particular, ERO's would preserve the set of solutions to Ax=0, i.e., the kernel, so, by rank-nullity, they would preserve the column space, and therefore its dimension, i.e., the rank of A.